# BlueSocket saying Connection Refused when connecting to Python Socket Socket

Tags: python, ios, swift, sockets, tcp

For a iOS app I'm making, it needs to connect to a python socket server. For the iOS application i'm using Swift 3 and i'm using [BlueSocket](https://github.com/IBM-Swift/BlueSocket) When I try to connect to the server with the correct IP and Port, it always returns Connection Refused and I don't see the connection on the server. BlueSocket is set to a TCP Client and the python server is also a TCP Server, so i'm confused on why its not working.

Does anyone know/understand why it won't connect to the server?

The iOS swift code is this:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
import SystemConfiguration
import SystemConfiguration.CaptiveNetwork
import Socket

let ssid = "SSID"
let server = "192.168.0.24"
let port = 8000

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBOutlet weak var ideaLabel: UILabel!

@IBAction func generateButton(_ sender: Any) {

    func isInternetAvailable() -> Bool
    {
        var zeroAddress = sockaddr_in()
        zeroAddress.sin_len = UInt8(MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: zeroAddress))
        zeroAddress.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)

        let defaultRouteReachability = withUnsafePointer(to: &zeroAddress) {
            $0.withMemoryRebound(to: sockaddr.self, capacity: 1) {zeroSockAddress in
                SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(nil, zeroSockAddress)
            }
        }

        var flags = SCNetworkReachabilityFlags()
        if !SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(defaultRouteReachability!, &flags) {
            return false
        }
        let isReachable = (flags.rawValue & UInt32(kSCNetworkFlagsReachable)) != 0
        let needsConnection = (flags.rawValue & UInt32(kSCNetworkFlagsConnectionRequired)) != 0
        return (isReachable && !needsConnection)
    }
    func getSSID() -> String? {
        var ssid: String?
        if let interfaces = CNCopySupportedInterfaces() as NSArray? {
            for interface in interfaces {
                if let interfaceInfo = CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo(interface as! CFString) as NSDictionary? {
                    ssid = interfaceInfo[kCNNetworkInfoKeySSID as String] as? String
                    break
                }
            }
        }
        return ssid
    }
    func generateIdea() -> String? {
        let RNumber = arc4random_uniform(23)


        var idea = ""

        //(A bunch of code to get a idea for offline mode)

        return String(idea)
    }



    let InternetConnect = isInternetAvailable()


    if (InternetConnect == isInternetAvailable()){
        print("Internet Connection Verified")
        if (getSSID() == ssid){
            print("SSID Verified")

            let s = try! Socket.create()
            try! s.connect(to: server, port: 8000)
            print("Connceted to server")

            try! s.write(from: "01")
            print("String send")

            let idea = try! s.readString()
            print("Idea Received")
            ideaLabel.text = idea

            s.close()
        }
        else{

            print("SSID Verification Failed")
            ideaLabel.text = generateIdea()
        }

    }
    else {

        ideaLabel.text = generateIdea()
        print("Internet Connection Verification Failed")

    }
}
```

}

Explanation of swift client:

When a button is clicked to generate a idea, the app first checks to see if it can connect to the internet, if it can it then checks to see if its on the set internet network by checking the SSID(The server is going to be a lan server, so it only works on the set network)If it can't connect to the internet or its not on the correct network, it chooses a from a limited amount of ideas that are stored on the app. If it can connect to the internet and its on the right internet network, it attempts to connect to the server and get a idea from the server.

The python socket server code:

```
import socket
import sqlite3
from random import randint

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_address = ('localhost', 8000)
print("Starting Server")
s.bind(server_address)
print("Waiting for client")
s.listen(1)
alive = True

while(alive == True):
    connection, client_address = s.accept()
    print(client_address)

    try:
        command = connection.recv(2)

        if (command == "01"):
            conn = sqlite3.connect('ideas.db')
            c = conn.cursor()
            file = open("maxID.txt", "r")
            maxID = (int(file.read()) + 1)
            ideaNumber = (randint(1,maxID),)
            c.execute('SELECT * FROM ideas WHERE id=?', ideaNumber)
            idea1 = c.fetchone()
            idea = str(idea1)
            conn.close()
            idea = idea.translate(None, "1234567890'(),u")
            print("Your idea is:")
            print(idea)
            connection.send(str(idea))

    finally:
        connection.close()
```

Explanation of python socket server:

When the server gets a client, it waits to get a command. In this server, there is only 1 command, which is to get an idea. That command is "01". When it gets that command the first thing it does is gets the amount of ideas stored in the database. That will be written in the maxID.txt file, so it reads it. Then randomly chooses a random idea ID, then it gets that idea from the database by using the ID. Then it takes that idea and sends it to the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was on the python server. The issue was that I set the host to localhost, instead of leaving it blank.

This:

```
server_address = ('localhost', 8000)
```

Should've been:

```
server_address = ('', 8000)
```